# Can we prove $T : R^n \rightarrow R^n$ $T(x_1,x_2,...x_n) = ((x_1+x_2+...x_n),...,(x_1+x_2+...x_n))$ ,is diagonalizable by induction (by finding e.v)?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, induction, diagonalization

Let $T : {\Bbb R}^n \to {\Bbb R}^n$ be defined by

$$ T(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = ((x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n), \dots,(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n))$$

It is possible to prove that $T$ is diagonalizable by induction (to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors) for every $n \geq 2$?

It is obvious, we need to find $n$ eigenvectors to prove that T is diagonalizable for every $n ≥ 2$. If we  look at the equation $T(v) = λv$ we can see that $n$ is a sum of $x_1,...x_n$ so it is an eigenvalue to the eigenvector $(1,....1)$.If we will take the standard base for $R^n$ we will get that representation matrix is $[T]_
{\displaystyle {\mathcal {E}}}$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 1& ....& 1 \\
.........\\
1 & ......& 1
  \end{pmatrix} $ so the eigenvalues are $n$ and $0$ but how calculate it ? We can't use the charectsitcstic polynomial because calculating $det$ of that matrix takes too long. We can use induction to prove it on a smaller matrices (also on calculating the eigenvectors)?

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title. Besides, I don't understand how $T$ is defined.

Comment: Am I right that $(Tx)_{m} = x_1 + \ldots + x_m$, where $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$?

Comment: Hi, I just fixed it, thanks @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @openspace exactly, in every row in the vector $R^n$ (just wrote it as a row for because it it simpler.

Comment: It might or might not help to note that $T$ is given for all $v$ by the formula $T(v) = \langle v, w \rangle w$ where $w = (1,1,\dots,1)$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the usual dot product

Comment: Still not clear what $T$ is equal to!

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis now it is clear?

Comment: It is not clear. The first component of $T(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ is $(x_1+x_2,...x_n)\,.$ What number is that?

Comment: Hint: the matrix $T$ contains only $1$ and is therefore symmetric. What do we know about the diagonalizability of symmetric matrices?

Comment: Hint 2: the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $\lambda^n-n\lambda^{n-1}\,.$ To prove that by induction you develop the determinant by the first row or first column (Laplace expansion). Hint 3:  $n-1$ linearly independent eigenvectors to the eigenvalue zero are easy to find and so is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $n\,.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
e_i=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)
$$
be the vector in $\mathbb R^n$ with all entries equal to 0, except the $i-$entry which is equal to 1.

Then
$$
T(e_i-e_{i+1})=0, \quad i=1,\ldots,n-1,
$$
and
$T(e_1+\cdots+e_n)=n(e_1+\cdots+e_n).$

So, the $e_i-e_{i+1}$ and $e_1+\cdots+e_n$ are all eigenvectors of $T$, and they are linearly independent. Hence, $T$ is diagonalizable.

Another faster way to show that $T$ is diagonalizable is to observe that $T^2-nT=0$.